# Is there a way to configure lxd containers with cloud config at provision time?

Tags: lxc

Specifically, with the CLI tools- not openstack.

I'm looking at what a local dev setup with lxd might look like but am coming up empty handed when it comes to configuring new containers.

Are there any idiomatic (or otherwise) ways to configure lxd containers? Should I be looking at something more immutable like docker images?

Thanks. Any resources or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 16):

So there are multiple ways you can do so, either directly for a container:

```
lxc init ubuntu: CONTAINER
lxc config set CONTAINER user.user-data - < cloud-init-config.yml
lxc start CONTAINER
```

Or even shorter:

```
lxc launch ubuntu: CONTAINER --config=user.user-data="$(cat cloud-init-config.yml)"
```

Or through a profile:

```
lxc profile create dev
lxc profile set dev user.user-data - < cloud-init-config.yml
lxc launch ubuntu: CONTAINER -p default -p dev
```

Comment: How can .sh files be used instead of .yml? Is there a tutorial already available on this topic?

Comment: The above is in reference to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44456522

Answer (score 5):

I had a slightly more specific question than the OP but it took me a while to work out what I was doing wrong. I thought I would post it here to help anyone else getting similarly stumped.

I wanted static networking settings for an LXC/LXD Ubuntu 16.04 container hosted on Ubuntu 16.04. I started by trying what Stéphane [wrote](https://askubuntu.com/a/701629/28965) but it wasn't working. All I ended up with was the default DHCP-attempting container with an IPv6 link local, as there is no DHCP being served in my configuration.

My initial YAML looked (something) like the following (taken from the [cloud-init](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/network-config-format-v1.html) docs).

```
network:
  version: 1
  config:
    - type: physical
      name: eth0
      subnets:
        - type: static
          address: 192.168.23.14/27
          gateway: 192.168.23.1
          dns_nameservers:
            - 192.168.23.2
            - 8.8.8.8
          dns_search:
            - exemplary.maas
```

And I was loading this into `user.user-data` as described above.

```
lxc config set CONTAINER user.user-data - < CONTAINER.cloud-init-config.yml
```

It wasn't until I found Stéphane's documentation in the [LXC/LXD source](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/stable-2.0/doc/cloud-init.md) that I realised I needed to load that value into `user.network-config`.

So my final YAML looked (something) like this.

```
version: 1
config:
  - type: physical
    name: eth0
    subnets:
      - type: static
        address: 192.168.23.14/27
        gateway: 192.168.23.1
        dns_nameservers:
          - 192.168.23.2
          - 8.8.8.8
        dns_search:
          - exemplary.maas
```

Then I loaded this into `user.network-config` instead.

```
lxc config set CONTAINER user.network-config - < CONTAINER.network-config.yaml
```

It seems like I will need to keep two different files per container: one for network settings to load to `user.network-config`; and one for other config to load into `user.user-data` unless I can find a way of using a single file for everything.

---

Another problem I found which wasn't obvious to me at all was trying to configure non-network components automatically.

```
lxc config set CONTAINER user.user-data - < CONTAINER.user-data.yaml
```

The following YAML applied with the command above (despite looking correct using `lxc config show CONTAINER`) did not create anything inside my container.

```
write_files:
  - content: |
    # My new /etc/foo.bar file

    Foo
    Bar

    path: /etc/foo.bar
```

The clue buried away in [User Data Input Formats, item 5: Cloud Config Data](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit#User_Data_Input_Formats) reads:

> begins with `"#cloud-config"` or `"Content-Type: text/cloud-config"`
>   This content is "cloud-config" data. See the examples for a commented example of supported config formats.

I don't believe this documentation is very clear. I could not get anything to work using the "Content-Type: text/cloud-config" form but I did find if you put `#cloud-config` on the first line, the YAML is parsed. I can only assume something isn't quite right, either my understanding, or someone's programming. It makes no sense to me that YAML you've explicitly loaded as the value of the key `user.user-data` should be used as anything other than cloud configuration data. Why else would anyone do that if it wasn't meant to be cloud configuration, and therefore why would a comment (which doesn't even use the normal shebang syntax) be **required**?

So, nonsense aside, the syntax which worked for `user.user-data` is:

```
#cloud-config

write_files:
  - content: |
      # My new /etc/foo.bar file

      Foo
      Bar

    path: /etc/foo.bar
```

Answer (score 3):

One liner I went with today, this one sets it in the default profile for new containers:

`echo -e "#cloud-config\nssh_authorized_keys:\n - $(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)" | lxc profile set default user.user-data -`

This one sets it in an existing container, but beware it will not work on containers that already booted as the SSH key stuff only gets done on first boot:

`echo -e "#cloud-config\nssh_authorized_keys:\n - $(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)" | lxc  config set CONTAINER_NAME user.user-data -`

Comment: Beware it will not only set this one key (`ssh_authorized_keys`) but it will overwrite whole `user.user-data`.